# Including unlabelled figures and tables in table of figures

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, labels

I would like to have a list of figures and tables, but some of my tables and figures I would like to be unlabelled, but when using `\caption*[short title]{long title}` I get issues. See the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption[Interesting table]{A really interesting table.}
\label{tab:interesting}
So interesting.
\end{table}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption*[Boring table]{A really boring table.}
\label{tab:boring}
ARGH, what's going wrong?
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

PS - **Most/all** of these unlabelled figures or tables will be at either the start or the end of the document (preambles, or appendices), if that helps.

[image: output]

Comment: `\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Your nice figure description}` and `\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{Your even nicer table description}`

Comment: Without the number looks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\caption*{…}` in combination with `\addcontentsline` depending whether you want the not numbered entry left aligned with the table numbers of the numbered entries or left aligned with the text of the not numbered entry use either:

```
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@table\endcsname}{table}{Boring table}
```

or

```
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@table\endcsname}{table}{\numberline{}Boring table}
```

Here an example, that shows the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption[Interesting table]{A really interesting table.}
\label{tab:interesting}
So interesting.
\end{table}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption*{A really boring table.}
% Use only one of the following lines:
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@table\endcsname}{table}{Boring table}
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@table\endcsname}{table}{\numberline{}Boring table}
\label{tab:boring}
ARGH, what's going wrong?
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've used `\csname ext@table\endcsname` instead of `lot`, because the extension of the auxiliary files for table may change. For example there are solutions for separate list of tables in the appendix, that use such redefinitions of `\ext@table`.

Note also, `\label{tab:boring}` does not make sense in the example. Package `caption` adds a waring about that to the `log`:

> ```
> Package caption Warning: \label without proper reference on input line 20.
> See the caption package documentation for explanation.
> ```

and a `\ref{tab:boring}` or `\pageref{tab:boring}` will result in:

> ```
> LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:boring' on page 1 undefined on input line ….
> ```

To avoid such problem, you can use something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption[Interesting table]{A really interesting table.}
\label{tab:interesting}
So interesting.
\end{table}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption*{A really boring table.}
% another suggestion for the table number in the list of tables
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@table\endcsname}{table}{\numberline{n.n.}Boring table}
% avoid problems with \label and \ref
\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabel{without number}% use text "without number" instead of number for the label
\makeatother
\label{tab:boring}
ARGH, what's going wrong?
\end{table}

See table~\ref{tab:boring} on page \pageref{tab:boring}.
\end{document}
```

[image: example with \label and \ref]

And to make this last solution more usable I would recommend to define your own command `\nonumcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand*{\nonumbername}{no number}
\newcommand*{\nonumbernumber}{n.n.}
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\nonumcaption}{ o m }{%
  \caption*{#2}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\addcontentsline{\@nameuse{ext@\@captype}}{\@captype}{\protect\numberline{\protect\nonumbernumber}#2}}%
    {\addcontentsline{\@nameuse{ext@\@captype}}{\@captype}{\protect\numberline{\protect\nonumbernumber}#1}}%
  \def\@currentlabel{\nonumbername}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption[Interesting table]{A really interesting table.}
\label{tab:interesting}
So interesting.
\end{table}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\nonumcaption[Boring table]{A really boring table.}
\label{tab:boring}
ARGH, what's going wrong?
\end{table}

See table~\ref{tab:boring} on page \pageref{tab:boring}.
\end{document}
```

Now, it is very easy to reconfigure the result for all such tables in the document preamble. And you can use the command also for figures or other floats.

Comment: The `\numberline{}` feature is something that looks good.